# Php after echo displayed blank screen

Tags: javascript, php

After echo is displayed, when you click 'ok', it just goes to the php file which displays nothing (so I end up with a blank screen), this happens twice, how can I fix it?

After the second echo is displayed, when you click 'ok', it must go back to the page so the user can do the reCAPTCHA, now it just goes to the php file which displays nothing (so I end up with a blank screen again)

```
<?php
// grab recaptcha library
require_once "recaptchalib.php";

// your secret key
$secret = "secretkey";

// empty response
$response = null;

// check secret key
$reCaptcha = new ReCaptcha($secret);

// if submitted check response
if ($_POST["g-recaptcha-response"]) {
$response = $reCaptcha->verifyResponse(
    $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"],
    $_POST["g-recaptcha-response"]
);
}

if ($response != null && $response->success) {
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
$to = "mail@hotmail.com";
$subject = "Voorstel ---.synology.me";
$suggest = $_POST['comment'];

$body = " NL\n Suggestie: $suggest\n";

echo "<script>alert('Je voorstel is verstuurd, wij proberen dit zo snel mogelijk te verwezelijken!');</script>";
//after previous echo is displayed, when you click 'ok', it just goes to the php file which displays nothing (so I end up with a blank screen)
$headers = "From: mail2@hotmail.com" . "\r\n";
mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers);
} else {
echo "Er ging iets mis, probeer opnieuw of contacteer de administrator op mail2@hotmail.com!";
}

} else {
echo "<script>alert('Vul de Captcha correct in!');</script>";
//after previous echo is displayed, when you click 'ok', it must go back to the page so the user can do the reCAPTCHA
//now it just goes to the php file which displays nothing (so I end up with a blank screen)
}
?>
```

Comment: DO not share your private keys publically

Comment: turn on error_reporting to see if it shows a fatal error

Comment: In your last else-statement the page has finished loading and you give the user a javascript alert, after the user clicks 'ok' surely nothing happens because the page finished loading.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead an alert, how about a confirm that redirects the page?

```
<script>
if(confirm('Vul de Captcha correct in!')){
  window.location.href = "yourpage.php";
}
</script>
```

Don't forget to make sure your echo is correctly formatted.

```
echo "<script>
    if(confirm('Vul de Captcha correct in!')){
        window.location.href = 'yourpage.php';
    }
</script>";
```

To have the same effect regardless of the choice simply account for it with the if statement.

```
<script>
    if(confirm('Vul de Captcha correct in!')){
      window.location.href = "yourpage.php";
    }else{
      window.location.href = "yourpage.php";
    }
 </script>
```

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'yourpage' (T_STRING), expecting ',' or ';' in /volume1/web/JocanasNLsuggest.php on line 42

It gives me this error. If I replace yourpage.php with https://google.com/ I still get the same error. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: you must remove nextline. wrap all code in one line.

Comment: Thanks, it works now! When I press ok, the page reloads but when I press cancel, it ends the php and I end up with a white screen again. How can I make it so when you press cancel, it does the same as ok. Or is there any possibility to make the cancel button disappear?

Comment: Thank you so much!! It finally works after several hours strougling with Captcha!